# How to add Expires to Flash and Icon components

Tags: apache2, yslow, mod-expires

Yslow is currently giving Grade B for my site and also for "Add Expires Headers".

It says:

There is 1 static component without a far-future expiration date.

```
* (no expires) http://localhost/images/favicon.ico
```

The current Expires code in my apache.conf is like this:

```
    ExpiresActive On # enable expirations

    # expire after a week in the client's cache
    ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
    ExpiresByType image/png A604800
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A604800
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800

    ExpiresByType text/css A604800
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
```

So what should be the syntax for flash and icon components?

Even though Yslow is not showing for flash, I want to add Expires for flash components.

Can any one help me out in achieving this task?

Comment: Did this fix your issue? If not, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197963/remove-etag-from-favicon-ico/6840502#6840502

Answer (score 1):

A quick visit to homestarrunner.com with Firebug open says that the content type is `application/x-shockwave-flash` for flash and `image/x-icon` for favicon.