# Remove Etag from favicon.ico

Tags: apache, optimization, favicon, etag, yslow

using yslow on a project I am experiencing a "problem" I can not solve.

Yslow keeps complaining:

> There is 1 component with misconfigured ETags http://www.domain.com/favicon.ico

I have the following in my .htaccess file

```
# Add Proper MIME-Type for Favicon
AddType image/x-icon .ico

# Enable Apache's mod_expires Module
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 6 month"

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this:

```
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 years"
```

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 years"
</IfModule>

Header unset ETag
FileETag None
```

Comment: Yahoo is more aggressive. They use "plus 10 years". Yes, the RFC says not to go over 1 year, but it's just a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. this did not fix the issue for me in Drupal ( 7 ).

Adding these lines to my `.htaccess` file:

```
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800
```

Also added this line to my apache http config: (but can also be in your .htaccess file)

```
  FileETag None
```

And i disabled the icon / default icon on the admin/appearance/settings/[theme_name] page.

And finally copied the favicon.ico file to my site root and this DID fix this problem for me.

Kinda looks like something is wrong in Drupal here? :/

Comment: Same here with codeigniter. Copied ico to the root solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

none above helped for me but this works excellent:

```
<FilesMatch "favicon.ico">
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```